# jQuery Datatable custom sort

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hey guys so i got this datatable

```
var oTable = $("#products").dataTable({
    "aaData": [
        [1, "TEST1", "A"],
        ['NA', "NA1", "B"],
        ['NA', "NA2", "C"],
        [4, "TEST2", "D"]
    ],
    "aoColumns": [{
        "sWidth": "70%",
        "sClass": "center",
        "bSortable": true,
        "sType": "rankedNA"

    }, {
        "sWidth": "70%",
        "sClass": "center",
        "bSortable": false
    }, {
        "sWidth": "70%",
        "sClass": "center",
        "bSortable": false
    }]

});
```

I need a custom sort

```
    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['rankedNA-asc']  = function(a, b) {
        return rankedNASort(a, b);
    };
```

That always leaves the 'NA' values in the first column at the bottom of the table. No matter if its asc or desc, NA should be fixed at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

yeah... I kind of solved it not sure why am getting negative responses, would be cool to get a comment on why. anyways if anyone needs it this is the answer.

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["duration-desc"] = function (a, b) {
    const z = naturalSort(a, b, 2) * -1;
    return z;
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["duration-asc"] = function (a, b) {
    return naturalSort(a, b, 1);
}
function naturalSort (a, b, c) {
    if(a === 'NA') { 
      if(c == 2) {
       return 0
      } else {
       return 10000;
      }
    }
        const a2 = parseInt(a);
        const b2 = parseInt(b);
        return a2 - b2;
    }
```

Apologize upfront for the weird indentation...